# Number of ways of colouring grid

Tags: algorithm, permutation

There is grid of n x 1. You have to colour it with atleast r red cells, atleast g green cells, atleast b blue cells. (n + r + g <= n). Two patterns are said to be different if they differ in atleast one position. In how many ways u can colour it. (Solution can be either algorithmic or mathematical).

My attempt:

```
enter code here
int func(int id, int r, int g, int b)
{
     int ma = 0;
     if (id == n) {
        if (r > 0)
            ma++;
        if (g > 0)
             ma++;
        if (b > 0)
             ma++;
        return ma;
     }
     if (r > 0)
       ma += func(r-1, g, b, id + 1);
     if (g > 0)
       ma += func(r, g-1, b, id + 1);
     if (b > 0)
        ma += func(r, g, b-1, id + 1);

    if (r + g + b < n - id)  {
           ma += func(r, g, b, id + 1);
    }

    return ma;
```

}

Comment: Also, what is the acceptable time and space complexity for the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the number of them is `f(n,r,g,b)`, then we have the following recursion:

`f(n,r,g,b) = f(n-1,r,g,b)*3 + f(n-1,r-1,g,b)+f(n-1,r,g-1,b)+f(n-1,r,g,b-1)`.

Also we know the base cases: `f(1,1,0,0)=f(1,0,1,0)=f(1,0,0,1)=1`. Start from bottom and by above recursion build up f(n,r,g,b). (Is simple if you use memoization instead of for loops). the running time is `O(n*r*g*b)`.

**Update:** Your code is close to my answer but first I should say that it's wrong, second, you used naive recursion which causes to exponential running time, allocate an array of size n*r*g*b, to prevent from recomputing already computed answer. See [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/time-complexity-and-space-complexity-in-recursive-algorithm/13058#13058) for an instance of memoization.

Comment: Also, `f(n,r,g,b) = 0` when `r+g+b > n`. You may not get into this scenario if you 'start from the bottom', but that seems more complicated.

Comment: @Dukeling, Yes you are right, I didn't mention it because I thought is obvious, and is about detail of implementation.

Comment: Your recursion relation looks wrong.  Cases added up should be mutually exclusive, ie any given configuration should be counted in only one of the terms of the sum.  Consider, eg, r=g=b=1 and n=10.  The 9-configuration containing 3 each of r,g,b yields 3 new 10-configurations but your expression counts it as yielding at least 6.

Comment: @jwpat7, May be you are right, I'll think about it later, and if is wrong I'll fix it (I'm also not sure if is correct, but for making it surely correct seems to be easy to add another dimension to keep track of color of last item, which doesn't change the running time).